# Laravel 5.2 : Save request to cache

Tags: laravel, request

i have a problem.
i want to create order form, but i want to use more than 1 view, so i use more than 1 method controller. So how I can save the older request ( like to cache) and join to other request ??
because the database table is 1.

Comment: Use [session flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist Form Data Across Multiple Steps in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371630/persist-form-data-across-multiple-steps-in-laravel)

Comment: http://bicknoyle.com/blog/2015/09/29/building-a-multi-step-survey-with-laravel-5-1-part-1/